# NSURLConnectionDelegate methods not called when on background thread

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch, nsrunloop, mopub

I am using MoPub for ad mediation in my iOS app. I received a couple of user complaints about blocked UI when an ad is loading. I could replicate this only under certain low-quality network conditions.

My naive assumption was that all I had to do was call the `MPAdView.loadAd` from a background thread via `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{`, and update the UI with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` in the `adViewDidLoadAd` delegate method (that gets called when an ad has been loaded by the MoPubSDK).

But as it turns out, this did not work - the delegate method is never called.

I traced the problem back into the [MoPubSDK](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/blob/60f3bdf751c6445295c62f1ad6f031e1fd67e473/MoPubSDK/Internal/Common/MPAdServerCommunicator.m#L71), where a `NSURLConnection` is initialized via:

```
self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[self adRequestForURL:URL] delegate:self];
```

but the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods (like `connectionDidFinishLoading`) themselves are never called when executed on the background thread. It works when the call is made on the main thread.

I noticed that the "current mode" of `[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]` is "(none)" when executed on the background thread, but "kCFRunLoopDefaultMode" when executed on the main thread.

The NSURLConnection docs mention

> For the connection to work correctly, the calling thread’s run loop must be operating in the default run loop mode.

so I tried setting it explicitly using

```
 [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60]];
```

but this had no effect.

**So, what do I need to do to ensure that the NSURLConnection delegate methods get called when the connection is initialized in a background thread?**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after hours of searching, I wrote that question - and of course, 15 mins later, I find one possible solution on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023644/nsurlconnectiondelegate-methods-not-called-when-using-nsthread)...

```
self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:[self adRequestForURL:URL] delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[self.connection scheduleInRunLoop:runLoop forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[self.connection start];
[runLoop run];
```

This ensures that the NSURLConnection delegate methods are called.

(I now have a different problem "This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread." - but this is unrelated to the original question).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be scheduling the connection object on the main run loop instead of the current one.  That will not only avoid the issue of scheduling it on a nonfunctional run loop (what the heck?), but also will ensure that when a request finishes, the ad framework won't try to do UI operations on the wrong thread.